# Intel HD 4600 Graphics Glitched in 16.04

Tags: graphics, 16.04, intel-graphics

I've been running into a very frustrating issue trying to move to 16.04, the graphics output is completely glitched to the point the system is basically unusable.

[image]

This starts during the initial boot screen after selecting 16.04 in GRUB, and persists through logging into the desktop.

I have an intel i5-4590 (Haswell) that I use with the integrated HD 4600 graphics. I have been using this setup with 15.10 and 15.04 without an issue.

I initially upgraded via dist-upgrade, but I found the issue is present when booting from the install disc for Ubuntu, Ubuntu Gnome, and Ubuntu MATE as well when I went to do a fresh install. Applying the most recent pathces has not made a difference, neither has turning the Intel microcode drive on or off.

I've tried reinstalling `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, `libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri`, and `xserver-xorg-core` but no change.

Any guidance or suggestions appreciated!

```
    lshw -c video
      *-display
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 2
           bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
           version: 06
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
           configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
           resources: irq:34 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)

    uname -a
    Linux 4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:03:46 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Pointing you to UXA: https://askubuntu.com/questions/302132/integrated-graphics-does-ubuntu-work-better-with-intel-hd-graphics-4000-or-with/453676#453676

and https://askubuntu.com/questions/638231/how-can-i-switch-graphic-card-acceleration-from-sna-to-uxa

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. Unfortunately I have not been able to switch to uxa successfully. I added a 20-intel.conf file to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ the the 'AccelMethod" "uxa" option, but I see that SNA is still in use from the Xorg.0.log file.